# IOS Framework trouble load loading embedded resource plist file

Tags: objective-c, bundle

In my Iphone app, I previously loaded a standard plist file into a Dictionary, by doing the following code.  Recently I copied the source, and the plist file to a new bundle, which I compile into a framework and use in the original app.  All the code is running, but the plist loading code can't find the settings.plist file anymore.  Looking at the path, it still seems to be looking in the main app's files.

Do I need to update this bundle somehow to read the frameworks embedded resources?

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString  *path = [[bundle resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.plist"];
_plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 7):

If I'm understanding you correctly, yes.

`+[NSBundle mainBundle]` returns the `NSBundle` object that corresponds to the directory where the current application executable is located. So in short, it's going to return the main application's bundle, which is not what you want (you want the bundle of a framework, within your application's bundle).

Since you want to obtain the bundle for your framework, if the code to load that plist resides in the framework itself, you could do something like this:

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
```

which would then return the bundle for the framework. Or more specifically, the bundle in which that class (this code) resides.

Comment: This is the right idea, but bundleForClass still appears to be returning the same bundle as mainBundle.  I think it is because the framework is compiled and included in the mainBundle's app, and becomes a part of it at runtime.

Comment: So it's not truly a framework, rather you've just got some sort of secondary bundle within your application's bundle? If so, then you can try something like:  NSBundle* bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyBundle" ofType:@"bundle"];  or whatever it might be.

Comment: It is a framework, I just happen to have it in the same project as the app right now, for simplicity in building.  A .framework file is generated, and included in the app itself as a framework resource.   (http://longtrieuquang.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/how-to-build-custom-ios-framework-with-xcode/)

Comment: OK that's fine. Did you try my suggestion of using -[NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:] to help locate the framework bundle inside your app bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but hoping this helps someone...

Trying to locate a resource (in my case, a nib file) in an embedded framework, `NSBundle.mainBundle()` was not working for me either. I managed to locate it by using this extremely roundabout method (Swift code):

```
if let frameworkURL = NSBundle(forClass: MyClass.self).URLForResource("MyFrameworkName", withExtension: "framework", subdirectory: "Frameworks") {
    if let bundle = NSBundle(URL: frameworkURL) {
        if let resourceURL = bundle.URLForResource("MyResourceName", withExtension: "nib") {
            // do something with resourceURL
        }
    }
}
```

Change `MyClass`, `"MyFrameworkName"`, `"MyResourceName"`, and `"nib"` as appropriate for your needs.

Seems like there must be a better way, but not sure what it is, yet.

(Tip: explore the files in your compiled app bundle by getting the value of `NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath`, then opening that path in Finder.)

Comment: I change my class for my myFramework but I'm getting this error:Cannot convert value of type module <myFramework> to expected argument type AnyClass